the virtual studio manager of android studio is not syncing with vs code as an emulaotr , I can't present my flutter code in any mobile dimensions
I have installed android studio to diplay the output of the flutter code in the dimensions of android monbile like pixel 6 etc as an emulator  ,  but it is not syncing with vs code , vs code only allows me to display the with edge or chrome , can you help me to make the android studio virtual studio manager act as an emulator in vs code.
I have tried correcting all the paths again and again in the enviorment variables but the android studio is not working as an emulator in vs code
